# WordPress website white labeling?

Tags: wordpress

We have many (hundreds) of clients that require basic, content-oriented websites. We are currently using simple WordPress deployments for these clients, but would like to make things more simple.

Is there a tool that exists that will let us white-label, or "re-use", a basic WordPress website and simply injecting some text and images into it to create a whole new website?

The process would look something like:

```
1. Have new client that needs website
2. Gather some client info (phone number, images, biography, etc.)
3. Inject this info into a previously created WordPress "template" site
    (we would use the same template for all clients)
4. Pick a WordPress theme
5. And done. We now have a rebranded WordPress site for this client with minimal work        
     done.
```

Step **3** is where we need help? Is there something that already exists that can do this? If not, what is a good method to do this "injection"? We were thinking just creating a small app that would go through the template WordPress site and do a find-and-replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be good to simply write a plugin which would allow you to gather exactly what info you need in a settings panel there, then inject the information into whatever theme you're using from there.

So it would be a relatively simple step as you create new sites to install the plugin, use it to add information, etc. (Perhaps if most of it is client information, it stores the information with admin user information).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to be able to re-use your branding, you could do them in your theme's function.php, so its kind of "portable"

For example, when I re-brand a wp site, and customize their wp-login. Change logos and stuff.
and things like, hide menu of theme-editor, plugin-editor, etc

all goes together, and I put the codes in the **functions.php**

Comment: I don't believe this would work. Functions.php is only executed for a particular theme file, meaning functionality is lost if we change the client's theme. We need to be able to inject information into a basic WP site (the template site), and then change the theme of that site to look good.

Comment: ah, did you just meant to "hack" and modified the core php files? I think that would be troublesome todo.

Comment: That is what we were thinking, but it is very tedious. Maybe we could store variables in the template site and it grabs the "injected" information from a database...

Comment: yeah, will be very tedious one.
Depends on how much you want to whitelabel.

Are you going to prevent them from auto-updating their WP installations?
if they auto-update, your brandings could be removed.

then are you allowing them to change WPthemes from time to time?

if you make the branding via code level, as plugin.
are they allowed in editing/adding plugins?